# Keep gridview rows order sorted by jquery after post back

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, tablesorter

I have an editable gridview and I sort it with jquery plugin 'tablesorter'. Each post back I save the order in cookie and recreate it after. But sometimes when i click on edit the editable row jumps to the start or end (depends on sort order) of the gridview and I don't know why it happens.

I need to make the editable row stay where it was, I looked everywhere, will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have all.

This is a complicate issue here, you change the html struct on the page and you expect the code behind to follow and understand this changes.

Ether make sort with the code behind, ether make edit with direct ajax call, ether place your gridview on an update panel and remove jquery sort).

Comment: I am using jquery sort because I need multiple sorting. The gridview is already in update panel.

Comment: I am using jquery sort because I need multiple sorting. The gridview is already in update panel. Is there maybe another way to make editable gridview with multiple sorting? Trying to do this for couple of days, will appreciate an answer a lot.

Comment: @Dazhush if the gridview is all ready in update panel, then when you make the resort ?

Comment: you make the gridview, then you make sort, then you click on edit, and then you get the update with the editor open, but you need to resort the table so the editor stay on the same position - where do you make this resort ?

Comment: It happens automatically as a asp.net Gridview feature. (edititem template) OnRowEditing event I am databinding the Gridview again. Without jquery sorting (or with gridview sorting) editable row stays at the same position. (hope this is what you mean)